# using pagination with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Pagination not works on my project and nothing was shown (no pagination - 1,2,3,... and i get the full results from database).

**Here my controller:**

```
public function list_result()
{

    $this->run_cache();
    $this->initialize_limit();
    $limit = (is_int($this->uri->segment(2)))?$this->uri->segment(2):0;
    $offset = $this->result_limit;
    $query = "SELECT title,user_photo,id,created_date
              FROM result";
    $query .= " LEFT JOIN users ON result.user_id = users.user_id ";

    if ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'popular') {
        $this->session->set_userdata('filterQuery', " ORDER BY result.id DESC ");
    }
    $query .= " WHERE state = 1";
    $query .= $this->filter_query();

    if (!$this->session->userdata('filterQuery')) {
        $query .= " ORDER BY created_date DESC ";
    }
    $query .= " LIMIT " . $limit . "," . $offset;
    $grow['result'] = $this->db->query($query)->result();

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . "site";
    $config['total_rows'] = count($grow['result']);
    $config['per_page'] = $this->result_limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="uk-pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="uk-active"><span>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $grow['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $grow['site'] = $this;
    $this->load->view('share/list_result', $grow);
}
```

**My view:**

```
<?php 
if (count($result) > 0) {
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        ?>
        show results here
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $links; ?></p> <!-- Nothing shown here -->
<?php } else { ?>

            No Result Found
<?php
}
?>
```

Can you help me to find where i have made a false here ?

Comment: do `print_r($result)` into view and check what result are getting

Comment: $config['total_rows'] = count($grow['result']);  // error, here you need to provide the total count of datas (without limit)

Comment: check your set limit not working in your query.

Comment: @MayankVadiya I get all results from database ... no pagination.

Comment: @Rijin Now i get the pagination numbers 1,2,3,4 but when i change page i get the full results without changes.

Comment: @pawansen set limit works well.

Comment: make your page number is uri->segment 2 or 3

Comment: @Rijin limit work well, the problem is when i click for example on page 2, i have the same results as page 3, page 4 and others.

Comment: either set $config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE; or calculate limit using page no. ie add this line after first line $limit = ($limit * $this->result_limit) - $this->result_limit;

Comment: you can click page 2 got same result please recheck offset.

Comment: @Rijin i get error when i use your code, $limit return all time 0 you are right, i changed uri->segment 2 or 3, 4,5,0,1 but nothing ... problem is there and i can't figure it out.

Comment: @pawansen offset set to 15 and work well.

Comment: please put full url on comment box i will check.

Comment: I working locally sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here how i processed in order to solve the problem.
For users that have same problem and googled to here.

I changed:

```
$limit = (is_int($this->uri->segment(2)))?$this->uri->segment(2):0;
```

To

```
$limit = (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(2)))?($this->uri->segment(2) - 1):0;
```